# SQL Table design for tracing damages in a trailer

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design

I want to design a SQL table, where I can save all the damage marked in an image of a trailer, from the back, front, left, right, floor and ceiling, this has to be done when the trailer is leaving the base and when return to the base.

```
http://previews.123rf.com/images/dymentyd/dymentyd1511/dymentyd151100021/48099625-Front-back-top-and-side-semi-trailer-for-truck-projection-Flat-illustration-for-designing-icons-Stock-Vector.jpg
```

I think, I can divide every images in nine pieces, like this:

```
 ________________
|____|_____|_____| 
|____|_____|_____| 
 o o          I
```

and click on the corresponding spot with a damage, this could be one or more.
but with 6 sides and 9 pieces it would be 54 spots.

There are like 500 trips a day and more than 800 trailers, of course not all the trailers are going to have a damage on a trip, but when they come back to the base, we want to know if there is any new damage, so we need to compare the before and the after.

How it would be the best way of doing this? so I can do a select query and compare the data.

I think having 54 columns in a table for the same thing is not a good idea, maybe something like a column [damage] and insert the number(s) of the spot(S) 1 to 54.

```
 _______________
|Trailer| Damage| 
|-------|-------| 
|t-3534 | 1,3,54| 
|t-7523 | 23    | 
|t-3562 | 11,12 |
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct to avoid the column-per-damage-location design but your suggested alternative can be improved.

As a first step I would change from recording all individual pieces of damage to a trailer in the same record to storing each in it's own record. This would enable you to track the nature of each individual piece of damage and also to record multiple pieces of damage in the same location.

```
Trailer   Location Description
t-3534         1   Minor scratch
t-3534         3   Minor dent
t-3534        54   Smashed tail-light
t-3534        54   Loose fender/bumper
```

Other enhancements that you might consider

- Track when damage happened using a date/time column or reference to a trip table
- Change description to a reference to another table with pre-defined damage types
- location could be more "granular" e.g. split into two parts "side" and "position"

All of these are of course dependent on other requrements that you may have

Comment: Thanks for your help, I like the idea of its own record and the other enhancements , I will make does changes and i will let you know how it works. Thanks again.